# Php artisan issue

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm facing the issue when i run php artisan command,first print p then command result.Screenshot is given please solve my problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm missing the issue here?  What is the issue you are having? Only thing i see is a minor 'bug' , and thats that its showing the letter `p` while echoing. But artisan still did his job, seeing that it created the event and listener successfully

Comment: yeah artisan is still working fine but the letter p shown in view page.

Comment: You can see p at left top of the above view image.